# python how to find unique pairs from 2 lists

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I have the following list of lists:

```py
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

and I want to generate something like the following:

```py
[1,4]
[1,5]
[1,6]
[2,4]
[2,5]
[2,6]
[3,4]
[3,5]
[3,6]
```

What can produce the expected result? To clarify, I'm looking for all unique pairs of 1 item from each of the two sublists.

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(list(itertools.product(*data)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product()` with list unpacking to generate tuples containing one element from each sublist. You can then use `map()` to transform each of those tuples to lists.

```py
from itertools import product
list(map(list, product(*data)))
```

This outputs:

```py
[[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for x in data[0]:
    for y in data[1]:
        result.append([x, y])
```

or one line:

```
[(x,y) for x in data[0] for y in data[1]]
```

that will give you a list of tuples

list of lists:

```
list(map(list, [(x,y) for x in data[0] for y in data[1]]))
```